# Change boot hard drive Dell Dimension 9150

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

Does anyone here know how to change what hard drive the Dell Dimension 9150 boots to? Mine is always booting to the first one, Win7, when I want to boot to the second one, Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a live cd and gparted it might work if you move the flag "boot" to Ubuntu instead of Windows ? Worth a try.

Comment: I'll try that, but according to this [link](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/dim9150/en/sm/syssetup.htm) it automatically boots to the first hard drive. I may have to switch the SATA plugs inside. I am currently installing ubuntu and and doing this with firefox during the install.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, many Dell laptops allow you to select boot device by hitting F12 during Powwer On Self-Test. You may need to go into setup (F2) to enable F12.

Alternatively, while in setup, you can simply change the boot order.